# Cassandra won't start in linux as a service

Tags: linux, cassandra, sudo

I have a debian linux image running on Google compute. Can successfully get cassandra working with "sudo cassandra" or "sudo cassandra -f" but then as soon as I log off this stops working. But when I try to run this as a service it simply doesnt say anything and doesnt start it either! I installed it using the aptget package v2.1.

I've tried sudo service cassandra start. It looks like its doing something and then quits without any logs.

Please help me run this up as a service. I can't even locate where the logs are stored when I run it as a service.

Comment: sudo cassandra -f & should work for you

Comment: @SandeepVaid, that will run it in the foreground. I need it running in the background and to keep it running after I log off. This is a production setup

Comment: does not adding '&' at back of unix command make it backgroud job?

Comment: When I log off (not shut down) it stops. The correct way to do it is sudo service cassandra start but nothing happens

Comment: It should start in the background with sudo cassandra, if this isn't persisting past you logging out something else is most likely wrong

Comment: @user3428172 It sounds like you following these instructions for 2.1 using apt-get: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/install/installDeb_t.html. Is that right? If after running `sudo service dse restart` then `sudo service dse status` shows that it's not running, check the log files in /var/log/cassandra. If it quits running without writing *any* log files, it could be an out of memory condition (not enough free memory to even start Cassandra).

Answer (score 6):

I ran into this issue recently, and as BrianC indicated it can be an out of memory condition. In my case I could successfully start cassandra with `sudo cassandra -f` but not with `/etc/init.d/cassandra start`.

For me, the last log entry in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log` when starting as a service was:

```
INFO [main] 2015-04-30 10:58:16,234 CassandraDaemon.java (line 248) Classpath: /etc/cassandra:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/antlr-3.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.3.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/guava-15.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.3m.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jline-1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/netty-3.6.6.Final.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.0.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/snaptree-0.1.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/super-csv-2.1.0.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-2.0.14.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra-thrift-2.0.14.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/apache-cassandra.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/stress.jar:/usr/share/java/jna.jar::/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar:/usr/share/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.2.5.jar
```

And nothing afterwards. If it is a memory problem you should be able to verify this in your syslog. If if contains something like:

```
Apr 30 10:53:39 dev kernel: [1173246.957818] Out of memory: Kill process 8229 (java) score 132 or sacrifice child
Apr 30 10:53:39 dev kernel: [1173246.957831] Killed process 8229 (java) total-vm:634084kB, anon-rss:286772kB, file-rss:12676kB
```

Increase your ram. In my case I increased it to 2GB and it started fine.

Comment: Any ideas on what it might be if i don't even get any system.log file created?

Comment: Cassandra installed using the deb package currently does not start when using a Java version > 8. For me using update-alternatives to java 8 solved the problem.